# Can I somehow tell Resharper about the type of the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, resharper

We have Views and ViewModels in different assemblies. Views' assembly has the reference to the VMs. (sometimes we need code behind).

ViewModel's DataContext is set in code, not in XAML. Thus nor VS neither Resharper can help as with intellisense and Resharper also gives a lot of warnings.

Is there any directive for Resharper we can set in XAML comments to say that we intend to use the View with VM of a particular type?

Update:

Nice [blogpost](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/) as addition to the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately Resharper will not (and won't be able to) resolve the ViewModel when it is placed in the codebehind. The only way this works is by placing it in the .DataContext property of a UIElement within your XAML. What is your rationale for placing it in the codebehind and perhaps I can help further?

Comment: We use constructor dependency injections for VMs. VMs can access each other through VmManager. We prefer VMs to have the right to decide how navigation will work. Views have no transitions at all just bindings to command and properties. And we use codebehind for tweaking fokus behavior or input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue and resolved it by using the design time support in XAML to get intellisense support in the XAML editor which also satisfies Resharper binding validation.

Note the d: namespace used in the code snippet below. This will be ignored at runtime. You can also use a ViewModelLocator which will add design time (Fake) repositories to the IoC container removing any dependencies from external sources like web services or other data sources.

XAML design time support:

```
<local:ViewBase
    ...
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignInstance Type=viewModel:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}">
```

XAML ViewModelLocator:

```
<local:ViewBase
    ...
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    viewModel:ViewModelLocator.ViewModel="MainViewModel" >
```

ViewModelLocator:

```
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            Container.RegisterType<IYourRepository, YourDesignTimeRepository>();
        }
        else
        {
            Container.RegisterType<IYourRepository, YourRuntimeRepository>();
        }

        Container.RegisterType<YourViewModel>();
    }
```

Comment: By far the best answer!

Comment: "The namespace prefix "mc" is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

If you set a ViewModel into the .DataContext property of a UIElement in your XAML as a placeholder, it will be replaced when you set it at runtime via your constructor injected ViewModel.

So you could have

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Pages:WelcomeLoadingViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Then in the UserControls constructor have

```
public WelcomeLoading(WelcomeLoadingViewModel viewModel)
{
   this.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

OR

```
public HomePage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();

   this.DataContext = ViewModelResolver.Resolve<HomePageViewModel>();
```

This would mean that you would get Binding and Resharper support as they can reflect the ViewModels from the XAML Datacontext. But also enjoy the benefits of Dependancy Injected ViewModels, as the VM would be replaced at runtime from your DI Container.

Comment: This mean we must provide parameterless constructors for our VMs.

Comment: Yes it does - but only for the sake of being able to render them in Xaml. Use your normal constructor for your VM, but with an empty constructor overload. Remember since you are essentially hot-swapping your VMs when the View is built - the DI container will still create the class using the longer, DI'd constructor when the VM is created and passed into the codebehind.

Comment: If you are very concerned about the possibility of the VMs being misused using an empty constructor - you could always throw an exception should the empty constructor be constructed when NOT in design time, therefore safely restricting the creation of the VM in that way to the Xaml layout engine. Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled or System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode will check this.

Comment: I'm more concerned that View will try to apply bindings what will cause reading the properties which require injected dependencies. I do not remember when bindings are applied for the first time in object lifetime. We also have compound VMs and compound Vs.

Comment: I mustnt be explaining the concept well enough. There are 2 scenarios here, Reading the VM in Design Layout & Reading the VM at runtime. Using the technique I have described above, at designtime the VM is completely empty and no values are populated as it has been created using the parameterless constructor from xaml layout generation. At runtime however the design layout VM is swapped for a VM that has been generated by a DI container and set in the codebehind. Therefore at design time you get binding & resharper support - and the 'real' reading of a fully populated VM is executed at runtime.

Comment: I understand you but if we define VM in XAML for design time and leave this XAML, the same VM will be created on View instantiation if I'm not mistaken. Yes, it will be substituted by the good one later. But won't bindings be applied for the first 'bad' VM? ... I've just noticed the injection of VM through constuctor, but we set View's DataContext after instantiation.

Comment: Does it really matter than bindings are set to an empty view model to begin with before it is swapped? Yes, there will be some very minor overheads - but imo they are worth the binding support. The constructor was just an example, see my edit for another usage.

Comment: It matters if property getter needs some dependencies which were not set.

Comment: Just add a condition in those particular properties to return a default value if the design mode is set.

Comment: 3 years have passed since then, but still worth mentioning:

This method can be combined with "d:DesignInstance..." method so real viewmodel is used for resharper intellisence, but designtime viewmodel is used for xaml editor preview.